# How can I get mean of every n rows and keep the date index?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a year index and a val index.

I would like to create a mean of every n rows of val and keep the corresponding year index.

Basically, the output would be (for n=2)

```
year val
1990 Mean(row1,row2)
1992 Mean(row3,row4)
1994 Mean(row5,row6)
1996 Mean(row7,row8)
```

How can I do this?

```
structure(list(year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013), val = c(84L, 67L, 72L, 138L, 
111L, 100L, 221L, 108L, 204L, 125L, 82L, 157L, 175L, 252L, 261L, 
185L, 146L, 183L, 245L, 172L, 98L, 216L, 89L, 144L)), .Names = c("year", 
"val"), row.names = 13:36, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry, I will remove it and post again.

Comment: Or just try to tweak one of the seven answers you already got to your question....

Comment: I would beware of answers that use the year value to compute the grouping unless you are sure the year values are a complete set of `Y` to `Y+N`. Your question said to add up every `n` rows, no guarantee that `n` rows was going to be `n` consecutive years (people, this is why we read the spec... and write tests...)

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for that detail..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A short one-liner solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,.(val=mean(val)), year-0:1]
#    year   val
# 1: 1990  75.5
# 2: 1992 105.0
# 3: 1994 105.5
# 4: 1996 164.5
# 5: 1998 164.5
# 6: 2000 119.5
# 7: 2002 213.5
# 8: 2004 223.0
# 9: 2006 164.5
#10: 2008 208.5
#11: 2010 157.0
#12: 2012 116.5
```

Comment: Also generalizes by switching `0:1` with `0:(n-1)`.

Comment: Provided the data.frame is order by year before.

Comment: (can just add `order(year)` in `i` to fix that of course ;-) )

Answer (score 7):

You could create a grouping variable using `rep`:

```
n = 2
dd$group <- rep(1:(nrow(dd)/n), each = n)
```

Then you can use your library of choice to do group_wise operations. I've used data.table.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)

#Getting the result is then trivial    
res <- dd[, .(year = min(year), mean_val = mean(val)), by = group]
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `rollapply` from zoo package

```
> library(zoo)
> res <- rollapply(df, width=2, by=2, FUN=mean)
> res[,1] <- floor(res[,1])
> res
      year   val
 [1,] 1990  75.5
 [2,] 1992 105.0
 [3,] 1994 105.5
 [4,] 1996 164.5
 [5,] 1998 164.5
 [6,] 2000 119.5
 [7,] 2002 213.5
 [8,] 2004 223.0
 [9,] 2006 164.5
[10,] 2008 208.5
[11,] 2010 157.0
[12,] 2012 116.5
```

alternatively:

```
rollapply(df, width=2, by=2, FUN=function(x) c(min(x), mean(x)))[, c(1,4)]
```

Answer (score 6):

`dplyr` solution - add a grouping variable (1,1,2,2,3,3 etc), then compute the mean of `val` within groups, and use the smallest `year` within groups, and then drop the grouping variable:

```
> require(dplyr)
> d %>% group_by(G=trunc(2:(n()+1)/2)) %>% 
   summarise(mean=mean(val),year=min(year)) %>% 
   select(-G)
Source: local data frame [12 x 2]

    mean year
1   75.5 1990
2  105.0 1992
3  105.5 1994
4  164.5 1996
5  164.5 1998
6  119.5 2000
7  213.5 2002
8  223.0 2004
9  164.5 2006
10 208.5 2008
11 157.0 2010
12 116.5 2012
```

Generalised into a function for `n`, and using a neater method to compute the grouping variable:

```
meanN =
function(df, n){
df %>% group_by(G=(0:(n()-1))%/%n) %>%  summarise(mean=mean(val),year=min(year)) %>% select(-G)
}

> meanN(d, 2)
Source: local data table [12 x 2]

    mean year
1   75.5 1990
2  105.0 1992
3  105.5 1994
4  164.5 1996
5  164.5 1998
6  119.5 2000
7  213.5 2002
8  223.0 2004
9  164.5 2006
10 208.5 2008
11 157.0 2010
12 116.5 2012
> meanN(d, 12)
Source: local data table [2 x 2]

      mean year
1 122.4167 1990
2 180.5000 2002
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `aggregate`, grouping on the rounded year values:

```
setNames(aggregate(val~I(2*floor((year-min(year))/2)+min(year)), data=dat, mean),
         c("year", "val"))
#    year   val
# 1  1990  75.5
# 2  1992 105.0
# 3  1994 105.5
# 4  1996 164.5
# 5  1998 164.5
# 6  2000 119.5
# 7  2002 213.5
# 8  2004 223.0
# 9  2006 164.5
# 10 2008 208.5
# 11 2010 157.0
# 12 2012 116.5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `seq` along with `colMeans` function

```
data.frame(Year = df[seq(1, length(df$year), 2), ]$year, Mean = colMeans(matrix(df$val, nrow=2)))

#   Year  Mean
# 1  1990  75.5
# 2  1992 105.0
# 3  1994 105.5
# 4  1996 164.5
# 5  1998 164.5
# 6  2000 119.5
# 7  2002 213.5
# 8  2004 223.0
# 9  2006 164.5
# 10 2008 208.5
# 11 2010 157.0
# 12 2012 116.5
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one-liner:

```
> t(sapply(split(dat,rep(seq(1,nrow(dat),2),each=2)),colMeans))
     year   val
1  1990.5  75.5
3  1992.5 105.0
5  1994.5 105.5
7  1996.5 164.5
9  1998.5 164.5
11 2000.5 119.5
13 2002.5 213.5
15 2004.5 223.0
17 2006.5 164.5
19 2008.5 208.5
21 2010.5 157.0
23 2012.5 116.5
```

You can then round the year if needed.